# Does Facebook Graph API Post Picture url (safe_image.php) expire?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm grabbing Facebook Post's pictures via Graph API call:

```
GET /mypageid/posts?fields=id,created_time,picture
```

Here's a sample response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1389378987988776_1745791089014229",
      "created_time": "2016-08-03T21:55:39+0000",
      "picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBQL02u4kJtLNFs&w=130&h=130&url=fbstaging%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fstaging_resources%2FMDExNzQ1NzkwNjg5MDE0MjY5Ojk5ODEyOTY4Ng%3D%3D&cfs=1"
    },
    {
      "id": "1389378987988776_1745301615729843",
      "created_time": "2016-08-02T18:10:53+0000",
      "picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD7O17OAki29Gus&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn2.obsnocookie.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F03%2F13995025_770x433_acf_cropped.jpg&cfs=1"
    }
}
```

Does the `picture` URL have an expiration date?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific expiration date afaik, but you should never rely on CDN links being available later according to Facebook. If you need them, you can download and store them on your own server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @luschn. I'm not wanting to be rude or something, but can you please provide me a facebook link saying why we should not rely on their CDN?

Comment: it´s what facebook devs commented multiple times in the official facebook dev group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ - just ask again.